# Debugging ASP.NET MVC apps in Monodevelop with XSP4

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-13.10, xsp4

I see from around the web that this question has been asked before elsewhere but I haven't found anything that fixes this problem in my case.

When I try to debug an ASP.NET MVC App from MonoDevelop 4.2.3 on Ubuntu, it fails with the error message

> Could not launch ASP.NET web server.The xsp4 web server could not be found. Please ensure that it is installed.

I have xsp4 installed already.

It was working previously, but went awry when I upgraded my Mono version to 3.2.1. In order to try to fix it, I have tried checking out, building, and installing the xsp source code from git.

Now, if I run:

```
xsp4 --version
```

It shows xsp4 version 3.0.0.0 is installed, and I can start it from the command line. MonoDevelop is still complaining though. If I do a which xsp4, it points to a script file containing this:

```
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe" "$@"
```

Which looks pretty good to me.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work in MonoDevelop? Or perhaps a way to configure MonoDevelop to debug through another web server?

Comment: Try installing it [again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34872143/2404470)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by copying the xsp4.exe and Mono.WebServer2.dll files to my application bin folder. I guess MonoDevelop probes the application bin folder as one of the potential locations for the web server executables. This works- the server starts as expected and the debugger attaches properly.